# Nested if statement in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

i want a desired output using batch file if loop
output should be like 
This is iteration for i 0 
This is iteration for j 1 
This is iteration for j 2 
This is iteration for j 3 
This is iteration for j 4
This is iteration for j 5
This is iteration for j 6
This is iteration for j 7
This is iteration for j 8
This is iteration for j 9
This is iteration for j 10
This is iteration for i 1
This is iteration for j 1
This is iteration for j 2
This is iteration for j 3
This is iteration for j 4
This is iteration for j 5
This is iteration for j 6
This is iteration for j 7
This is iteration for j 8
This is iteration for j 9
This is iteration for j 10
..so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /l %%i in (0 1 10) do (
    echo This is iteration for i %%i
    for /l %%j in (1 1 10) do echo This is iteration for j %%j
)
```